# React update array prop from child to parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Hello I am struggling to properly update my state from my child component to my parent.
Basically I am trying to set the current state to true onclick.

This is my parent component:

```
export default function Layout({ children }: Props) {
  const [navigation, setNavigation] = useState([
    { name: 'Dashboard', href: '/', icon: HomeIcon, current: true },
    { name: 'Create Fact', href: '/facts/create', icon: UsersIcon, current: false },
    { name: 'Documents', href: '/documents', icon: InboxIcon, current: false }
  ])

  return (
    <>
      <Sidebar navigation={navigation} setNavigation={setNavigation} />
```

This is my child Component (Sidebar)

```
type Props = {
  navigation: Array<{
    name: string
    href: string
    icon: any
    current: boolean
  }>
  setNavigation: (
    navigation: Array<{
      name: string
      href: string
      icon: any
      current: boolean
    }>
  ) => void
}

const Sidebar = ({navigation, setNavigation}: Props) => {
  const router = useRouter()
  const toggleNavigation = (name: string) => {
    // todo: Here I would like to properly update the state with the current selected navigation item (current)
    const newNavigation = navigation.map(nav => {
      if (nav.name === name) {
          nav.current = true
        return nav
      }
    })
  }

  return (
    <nav className="flex-1 px-2 pb-4 space-y-1">
      {navigation.map(item => (
        <span
          onClick={() => toggleNavigation(item.name)}
```

Comment: You're missing `setNavigation(newNavigation);` at the end, and you'll want to always return something. Use `nav.current = nav.name === name;` and `return nav;` in your map() function.

Comment: @ChrisG - That would directly modify objects inside the array, which is a [no-no](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly). :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Right, although isn't this an edge case? The array passed to the setter function is a completely new one, so it shouldn't matter in this case. It's still bad practice though I guess.

Comment: @ChrisG - Yeah, I don't think it would bite you often, but for instance, if the same objects were being used by multiple components, it easily could... :-) Unlikely in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three problems:

1. You never call `setNavigation` with your new array.
2. You don't clear `current` on the formerly-current item.
3. Although you're creating a new array, you're reusing the objects within it, even when you change them, which is against the [Do Not Modify State Directly](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly) rule.

To fix all three (see `***` comments):

```
const toggleNavigation = (name: string) => {
    const newNavigation = navigation.map(nav => {
        if (nav.name === name) {
            // *** #3 Create a *new* object with the updated state
            nav = {...nav, current: true};
        } else if (nav.current) { // *** #2 make the old current no longer current
            nav = {...nav, current: false};
        }
        return nav;
    });
    // *** #1 Do the call to set the navigation
    setNavigation(newNavigation);
};
```

---

Separately, though, I would suggest separating `navigation` out into two things:

- The set of navigation objects.
- The name of the current navigation item.

Then setting the navigation item is just setting a new string, not creating a whole new array with an updated object in it.

Answer (score 1):

[T.J. Crowder's solution and explanation are great](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70771457/5106620).
Additionally, you can write that logic in a shorter syntax. Just a preference.

```
const newNavigation = navigation.map(nav => {
  return nav.name === name 
    ? { ...nav, current: true } 
    : { ...nav, current: false }
})
```